# Создание Firebase Realtime

Tags: android, база-данных, firebase, firebase-database

Пытаюсь заполнить Базу данных. Мое приложение основано на категориях с продуктами. Я создал products,  в который буду вкладывать название Категорий, а в категории вложу название продуктов. В категории Бакалея начинаю заполнять : ключ "name", значение "Макароны" - добавил, все ок. Нажимаю +, чтобы еще добавить продукт - пишу ключ "name" значение "Рис", нажимаю добавить -  и почему-то Рис заменяет макароны, т.е. макароны удаляются просто, а на их место добавляется Рис. В чем заключается проблема ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Firebase Realtime можно записывать данные в виде массива. Для этого нужно каждый пункт нумеровать, как в массиве начинается счет, т.е. 0,1,2 и т.д.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]